# multiple data print using window.print()

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me? is it possible to print multiple data at once

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

i don't know where will i start coding it. i want to create a single page with print button there then after i click the print button once multiple data will be printed in one bond paper, one record per bond paper.I have 12,000 records need to be printed.I'm thinking that array function has something to do about it but i can't figure out whats the logic.Help me please! Thanks :)

Comment: You can print a multi-page document.

Comment: how?is it posibble in one click?  can i still use window.print function?

Comment: If the document is large enough, it will print across multiple pages.

Comment: hmm,i want to place one records of student in one page then print it, but the problem was i'm gonna do it one print per click in my code, this will be time consuming for me to print thousand records. i used array to call each record and put it in one page ready to print but there's so much records.